# Search data on the same table

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Help me
I have table. 
I have "where st_id in (10, 11)"

```
vf_id --> st_id
--------------
1 --> 10
1 --> 11
2 --> 10
3 --> 11
```

---

When searching with st_id is 10.11 then It gives the result as above

**I want the result is:**

```
vf_id --> st_id
--------------
1 --> 10
1 --> 11
--------------
```

Help me thanks so much

Comment: You need to provide us the full query you are doing and the table schema you are querying against. From the looks of it you may just need to add a GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a group by clause to your query you should be able to achieve something similar to what you ask e.g

```
SELECT vf_id, st_id
FROM table
WHERE st_id IN (10, 11)
GROUP BY st_id
```

However, this is really just going to tell you that there is at least one row with st_id=10 and at least one row where st_id=11 and you’ll lose the individual details about the rows if there are multiple rows that have st_id=10/11

Some more context about the problem would be useful to give a better answer

It might even end up being necessary to do a GROUP BY on more than one column if that is the sort of data you need

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what exactly you want, but from your sample data it appears you need something like these.

```
SELECT MIN(vf_id) AS vf_id,
       st_id
FROM   t
WHERE  st_id IN ( 10, 11 )
GROUP  BY st_id;
```

OR

```
SELECT vf_id,
           st_id,
-- In case you need other columns.
    FROM   (SELECT t.*,
                   row_number()
                     over (
                       PARTITION BY st_id
                       ORDER BY vf_id ) AS rn
            FROM   t
            WHERE  st_id IN ( 10, 11 )) b --exclude where if you don't need that
    WHERE  b.rn = 1
```